# Symfony2 bundles in a different directory?

Tags: php, symfony, autoloader

Here is the basic layout:

```
mywebsite
  shared
    bundles
      MyWebsite
        CoreBundle
  src
    MyWebsite
      MyProduct
        ABundle
```

`shared` is a submodule (git) but I need Symfony to be able to locate the shared bundles under the same namespace, ie:

```
namespace MyWebsite\MyProduct\ABundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use MyWebsite\CoreBundle as Core;

class Recipe extends Core\Entity\SimpleEntity {}
```

I have tried changing the composer.json file to add the new directory:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": [ "src/", "shared/bundles/" ] }
},
```

Is this possible? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Yup, should work that way. :)

Comment: Just try and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, once you edit the `composer.json` file you have to recompile the autoloader with:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```